Por alguma razão, quando coloco entradas no meu código em C que possuem acentuação o 'fgets' para de ler quando chega no acento
// FUNÇÃO PRINCIPAL
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions.c"

#define sucess 0;

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8"); // Permite acentuação e caracteres especiais da língua portuguesa

   char frase[335];
   system("cls"); // Limpa o terminal antes do inicio do programa

   printf("Digite a frase: ");
   fgets(frase, 335, stdin); // Deveria receber a string inserida pelo usuário 

   frase[strcspn(frase, "\n")] = '\0'; // Retira o \n do final da string

   printf("Frase recebida: %s\n", frase); // Testa a frase recebida

   int num_palavras = count_words(frase); // Conta o número de caracteres
   printf("Número de palavras: %d\n", num_palavras);

   system("pause");

   return sucess;
}

O código sendo compilado:
Compilação sem erros!
Primeiro exemplo de execução:
Observe que a frase foi recebida até o caractere acentuado: "é"
Segundo exemplo exemplo de execução:
Observe que caracteres especiais também não funcionam como o "ç"

Está usando o MinGW-w64? É uma versão com biblioteca de tempo de execução UCRT ou MSVCRT? MSVCRT é a versão mais antiga que não suporta UTF-8. E a UCRT é mais recente e é a melhor opção entre as duas, e suporta UTF-8.

E teste sem a linha setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8"); e veja se o problema ainda ocorre.

Configure o Powershell para usar UTF-8, pra isso dentro do powershell digite notepad $PROFILE, ele vai abrir um arquivo de script Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 no Notepad (e se não existir vai perguntar se deseja cria-lo), aí você adiciona a linha $OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding dentro no arquivo, salva o arquivo, então fecha e reabre o Powershell.

Se o Powershell falar que não conseguiu executar o script pois a política de execução do computador não permite, abra o Powershell como administrador e digite Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned para mudar a política de execução de scripts permitindo executar scripts.

Isabel ,  com certeza é algum erro nesse header "function.h" e "functions.c" , ou as configurações de seu compilador , pois sem eles o fgets funciona bem .
